# Can't get ImageViews to dynamically show in activity

Tags: java, android, imageview, dynamically-generated

I've been trying for hours now, looked on stackoverflow for solutions.
All the solutions that worked for others, didn't work for me, so maybe there is something I'm missing here.

```
    public void show(View layout){
    RelativeLayout linear = (RelativeLayout)layout.findViewById(R.id.linear);
    for(int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < map.get(i).size(); j++){
            ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
            switch(map.get(i).get(j)){
                case 0:
                    image.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.black));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    image.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.white));
                    break;
            }
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(32,32);
            params.setMargins(j * 32, i * 32, 0, 0);
            image.setLayoutParams(params);
            image.invalidate();
            linear.addView(image);
        }
    }
}
```

The image it has to draw is read from a text file with zero's and one's.
Because the function below is a class and not an activity, I pass the layout with it the ImageViews have to be in.

---

Solved:

This is how I fixed it:

```
    public void show(View layout){
    RelativeLayout linear = (RelativeLayout)layout.findViewById(R.id.linear);
    int imageRes;
    for(int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < map.get(i).size(); j++){
            ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
            switch(map.get(i).get(j)){
                case '0':
                    imageRes = R.drawable.black;
                    break;
                case '1':
                    imageRes = R.drawable.white;
                    break;
                default:
                    imageRes = R.drawable.white;
                    break;
            }
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(32,32);
            params.setMargins(j * 32, i * 32, 0, 0);
            image.setLayoutParams(params);
            image.setBackgroundResource(imageRes);
            linear.addView(image);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why dont you just use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` ?

Comment: @Jesper Klippel the code what you show is correct nothing worng so my assumsion is your are not getting proper data either in map array or from text file once debug and check

Comment: tried that before, changed it to RelativeLayout because someone in another Stackoverflow post did that. I fixed it though, I'll edit the post!

Comment: @Sandy yeah it's really weird, the array was filled right, the data it got was right (Logged it in the monitor) but somehow the images would not draw. I've got a solution though, it's in the first post.